# How can I prevent the closing of modal using setTimeout() in Ajax Jquery method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make the `index.php` page "automatically" loads the data every 2 seconds from MySQL table using `setTimeout()`. Problem is every time I click the View Details button from the second page (`order.php`) the modal loads up BUT closes immediately after 2 seconds.

**How can I prevent the automatic closing of modal when I click the View Details button and continue the refreshing of the div to load the data from MySQL table after closing the modal?**

**index.php (first php page)**

```
 // INDEX.PHP
 <body>
    <div id = "showCustomerOrder_div"></div>
 </body>

 <script>
 var interval = 2000;
 function displayCustomerOrder() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'order.php',
    data: { },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#showCustomerOrder_div').html(data);
    },
    complete: function (data) {
        setTimeout(displayCustomerOrder, interval);
    }
});
 }
 setTimeout(displayCustomerOrder, interval);
 </script>
```

**order.php (second php page)**

```
 // ORDER.PHP
 <?php
  $count = 0;
 while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $count++;
  $date = $rows['date_order'];
  $receipt = $rows['receipt_no'];
  $fullname = $rows['fullname'];
  $restoname = $rows['resto_name'];
  $total = $rows['Total'];
 ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo date_format($date,"m/d/y h:i:s"); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $receipt; ?></td>
    <td>
    <a href = "#orderDetails<?php echo $receipt; ?>" data-toggle = "modal" class = "btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
    </td>
</tr>

    <div class = "modal" id = "orderDetails<?php echo $receipt; ?>">
        <div class = "modal-dialog">
            <div class = "modal-content">
                <div class = "modal-header">
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-body">
                    <div class = "row">                     
                      <div class = "col"><?php echo $rows['receipt_no']; ?></div>
                      <div class = "col"><?php echo $rows['fullname']; ?> </div>
                      <div class = "col"><?php echo  $rows['Total']; ?> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <?php
}
 ?>
```

**Thanks a lot!**

Comment: I would make the last line `displayCustomerOrder()` but it is not visible why it closes - Where is `#showCustomerOrder_div` ?

Comment: Hi mplungjan, its included in the html part of the index.php page, I just put the Ajax Jquery method with the setTimeout() function

Comment: But if the modal is a child of showCustomerOrder_div then that would explain it

Comment: Can you help me on how will I solve that problem if it is a child of showCustomerOrder_div? Thanks :)

Comment: Don't make it a child of that div! Move it out and change modal-body instead

Comment: If I will move the modal outside of that div, How can I make the modal appear when I click the View Details button? Because this button is related on the data inside MySQL database <a href = "#orderDetails<?php echo $receipt; ?>"

Comment: Delegate: `$('#showCustomerOrder_div').on('click','#orderDetails',function(e) { e.preventDefault(); showModal(); });`

Comment: Thank you for that information :) But how can I make sure that the content of this modal will match the data of each row inside inside the table? I mean this part <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo date_format($date,"m/d/y h:i:s"); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $receipt; ?></td>

Comment: The bigger problem is how will the user click on anything that refreshes every 2 seconds?

Comment: Because what will appear inside the modal body is the $rows['fullname']; $rows['resto_name'];$rows['Total'];

Comment: Give the links a class and change to `$('#showCustomerOrder_div').on('click','.orderDetails',function(e) { e.preventDefault(); var dataCells = $(this).closest("tr").find("td"); /* here you can get each cell and insert into the modal */  });`

Comment: I'm sorry if I forgot to add that information that I also need to display the other MySQL data inside the modal body

Comment: I have nothing more to add. There is not enough html in your question for me to help you further. The comments I gave can be used to get any data on the page

Comment: I really appreciate  and grateful for your help :) just one question, how can I insert var dataCells = $(this).closest("tr").find("td"); inside the Modal? Thank you again.

Comment: Your code has **XSS** vulnerabilities

Comment: Hi Elroy Jetson, thank your for your feedback, can you show me or give me an example on how to do it properly? Thanks again.

Comment: @bryxjam https://www.wordfence.com/learn/how-to-prevent-cross-site-scripting-attacks/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```js
$("#container").on("click","[data-toggle=modal]",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var texts = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").map((_, cell) => cell.innerText).get(); 
  texts.pop(); // lose the link text
  $(".row").empty();
  $.each(texts, (_, text) => $(".row").append(`<div class="col">${text}</div>`));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>2019 05 10</td>
        <td>receipt 1</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>2019 05 11</td>
        <td>receipt 2</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Let me try that then I'll get back to you if I have questions. Thanks again :)